# mvn clean install, Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile

Tags: maven, jenkins

I want to connect my maven project to Jenkins, but I get the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov3Ys.jpg

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project AnimalShelter: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 12 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

So I changed the source and target to 11 or 10 but this also does not work. The same thing happens when I try to execute the following command : "mvn clean install". I think something is wrong in my settings but I don't know what.

```xml
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>12</source>
                    <target>12</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: I guess you need to set the `release` parameter for the maven compiler plugin.

Comment: How can I do this? @JFMeier

Comment: What is the output if you run `javac --version`?

Comment: This is my output: 
javac: invalid flag: --version
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: @gjoranv Forgot to tag you:)

Comment: Should have been `javac -version` (only one hyphen). Try also `mvn -V` which will show you both your maven version and java version. I suspect that you are compiling with an older version of the java compiler.